# getting duplicate entry error Django

Tags: python, django, error-handling, duplicates

Hi i am getting the duplicate entry when i am running this code but cant sure why it is happening Below is the code

```
def match_domain(request):
    user_domain_array = ['rohit@ghrix.com','rahul@ghrix.com','rishi@ghrix.com']
    getclientdomain = client_domain.objects.all()
    for i in getclientdomain:
            for u in user_domain_array : 
                if i.client_domain in u :
                    saveuser = User(email = u)
                    saveuser.save()
                    #return HttpResponse(u)
                else :
                    return HttpResponse("no")
```

getclientdomain  has **one** entry in **database** with the value of  **ghrix.com**  , it inserts the **first** element from the array to **database**  and after that throwing the **duplicate** entry error
please suggest me where i am doing a mistake .

Comment: You already have a user with one of those emails, clearly.

Comment: Please post the **full** traceback you get from your django log.

Comment: yes it inserts the first one and give error on second entry

Comment: Then that second entry is *already* present. Note that that has nothing to do with the other entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :
Send something different every-time for username field too , because looking at your save query , you only insert email So I think username field must be blank . So first time it insert the first row but 2nd time it doesn't insert and gives the duplicate entry error.